# Kettle Spoon fails find column with Database value lookup

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm using Kettle Spoon 7.1.0.0.12 from a while but now I'm experiencing a very weird problem.

I'm using Database Value lookup on a table in my Mysql db. The table field name I'm checking in "account_id" and I'm absolutely sure this column is on the db but I've this error:

```
2018/03/01 19:55:35 - Database lookup.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2018/03/01 19:55:35 - Database lookup.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException: 
2018/03/01 19:55:35 - Database lookup.0 - Field [account_id] couldn't be found in the table!
2018/03/01 19:55:35 - Database lookup.0 - 
2018/03/01 19:55:35 - Database lookup.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.databaselookup.DatabaseLookup.determineFieldsTypesQueryingDb(DatabaseLookup.java:236)
2018/03/01 19:55:35 - Database lookup.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.databaselookup.DatabaseLookup.processRow(DatabaseLookup.java:379)
2018/03/01 19:55:35 - Database lookup.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2018/03/01 19:55:35 - Database lookup.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

To be absolutely sure I tried to add a input table from the same table and I previewed data and I see the column!
I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong. I've to add I already use Database Value lookup and it works fine in other cases. Some advice?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I solved the problem doing a Tool -> Database -> Clear cache.